# Symfony 2 - Null checkboxes return no search results

Tags: php, mysql, database, symfony, doctrine

Whenever I check the "wetsoil" checkbox, my search results correctly filter through and display all the plant species that grow in wet soil, but whenever I don't check the checkbox, there are no search results. I want all the objects to appear if the checkbox is unchecked, not none of them. Not sure if my logic is incorrect, or maybe my syntax? In the database, "x" means yes.

My controller:

```
public function SearchResultsAction(Request $request)
    {
        $botanicalname = $request->query->get('botanicalname');
        $commonname = $request->query->get('commonname');
        $wetsoil = $request->query->get('wetsoil');

        $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Shrubs');

        $query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('p');

        $shrubs = $query
            ->where($query->expr()->like('p.botanicalname',':botanicalname'))
            ->setParameter('botanicalname', '%'.$botanicalname.'%')
            ->andwhere($query->expr()->like('p.commonname',':commonname'))
            ->setParameter('commonname', '%'.$commonname.'%')
            ->andWhere($query->expr()->like('p.wetsoil',':wetsoil'))
            ->setParameter('wetsoil', $wetsoil)
            ->orderBy('p.commonname', 'ASC')
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();

        return $this->render('shrubs/searchresults.html.twig', array(
            'shrubs' => $shrubs,
        ));
    }
```

And my input on the HTML page:

```
          <label for="wetsoil">Tolerates Wet Soil: </label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="wetsoil" value="x">
```

Note: I chose not to use the standard Twig syntax ({{ form_widget(form.wetsoil) }}) due to other technical reasons.

Front end:

```
 <table class="table table-striped">
                <thead>
                {% if shrubs | length == 0 %}
                <h3>No species match your search criteria. <a href="{{ path('shrubs_search')}}">Try again.</a></h3>
                {% else %}
                <tr>
                    <th>Common Name</th>
                    <th>Botanical Name</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr>

                    {% endif %}
                    {% for shrub in shrubs %}
                    <td><a href="{{ path('shrubs_show', { 'id': shrub.number }) }}">{{ shrub.commonname }}</a></td>
                    <td><a href="{{ path('shrubs_show', { 'id': shrub.number }) }}">{{ shrub.botanicalname }}</a></td>
                    {#<td>#}
                        {#<ul>#}
                            {#<li>#}
                                {#<a href="{{ path('shrubs_show', { 'id': shrub.number }) }}">show</a>#}
                            {#</li>#}
                            {#<li>#}
                                {#<a href="{{ path('shrubs_edit', { 'id': shrub.number }) }}">edit</a>#}
                            {#</li>#}
                        {#</ul>#}
                    {#</td>#}
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Comment: I assume checkbox is a boolean field in your db, If the parameter `$wetsoil` us `NULL`, its going to give you no results. Have you tried `var_dump`ing the `$wetsoil` variable when the checkbox is not checked?

Comment: Yeah, the var_dump shows that when it's checked the value is "x" but when it's unchecked the value is NULL.

Comment: It's not a boolean though, it's stored as a character ("x" for yes or "(" for no).

Comment: Well then how are you passing the `wetsoil` parameter? AJAX? You need to show the front end code.

Comment: That is a really poor db design. But that's not the concern right now.

Comment: I added the front end code. I know the database is poorly designed but I'm not permitted to modify it.

Comment: I don't see `wetsoil` anywhere in the edit. Also I need to see how its passed from the front to the method `SearchResultsAction`

Comment: In the controller: $wetsoil = $request->query->get('wetsoil'). Also, $wetsoil is not on the HTML page because I don't want to display the value of the $wetsoil, I just want to fitler the search results through it.

Comment: How do you expect `$request->query->get('wetsoil')` to have any value if its not even on the HTML page? Also your comment contradicts with your question. In the question you have provided HTML for the checkbox. **Please show how are you calling the action `SearchResultsAction`**